# How can I write a test function like this?

Tags: r

How can I write a function to check cases(x,y) by the two 
tests:

One

```
if y==rank(y)
```

Two

```
xranks <- rank(x)
yranks <- rank(y)
meanx <- mean(xranks)
meany <- mean(yranks)
covariance.term <- cov(xranks-meanx,y-meany)
sd.x <- sd(xranks)
sd.y <- sd(yranks)
if -1<= covariance.term/(sd.x*sd.y) <=1
```

and should return `TRUE` if both tests are passed, or `FALSE`, with warnings about which tests failed.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want, but as you didn't provide test cases, I am not sure if it works.

```
check.xy <- function(x,y) {
    xranks <- rank(x)
    yranks <- rank(y)
    meanx <- mean(xranks)
    meany <- mean(yranks)
    covariance.term <- cov(xranks-meanx,y-meany)
    sd.x <- sd(xranks)
    sd.y <- sd(yranks)
    testA <- all(y == rank(y))
    testB <- all(-1 <= covariance.term/(sd.x*sd.y) & covariance.term/(sd.x*sd.y) <=1)
    if (testA & testB) return(TRUE)
    else if (testA) warning("test two failed")
    else if (testB) warning("test one failed")
    else warning("tests one and two failed")
    FALSE
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik, it works. But return with another warning message that:                                                              In if (testA & testB) return(TRUE) else if (testA) warning("test two failed") else if (testB) warning("test one failed") else warning("tests one and two failed")  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used        any ways to solve that?

Comment: @RandyHuang Please see my edits. The changes, wrapping the tests in `all()`, should ensure that the tests match for all elements of `y` (I also made sure that test two returns a single value but this seems to be unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

I think to define each test in a single function, especially that we want warnings about which tests failed.

The 2 tests share the same environment, that why I defined them as a nested functions.

```
multitest <- function(x,y){
 test.covariance <- function(){
    xranks <- rank(x)
    yranks <- rank(y)
    meanx <- mean(xranks)
    meany <- mean(yranks)
    covariance.term <- cov(xranks-meanx,y-meany)
    sd.x <- sd(xranks)
    sd.y <- sd(yranks)
    cov.norm  <- covariance.term/(sd.x*sd.y) 
    res <- cov.norm  > -1 && cov.norm < 1
    if(is.na(res) || res > 0) warning('test covariance range failed',.call = FALSE)
    res
}
 test.rank <- function(){
   res <- all(y==rank(y))
   if(!res) warning('test rank failed')
   res
 }
 res <- test.covariance() && test.rank()
 !is.na(res)
}
```

some tests :

success

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
multitest(x,y)
[1] TRUE
```

failure rank

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
multitest(x,y)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In test.rank() : test rank failed
```

failure covariance

```
x <- rep(10,10)
y <- 1:10
multitest(x,y)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In test.covariance() : test covariance range failed
```